# This is NOT a number sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence, steganography

Since everyone is trying their hand at this type of puzzle, I've decided to create a number seq -

> We interrupt your Puzzle Solv*i*ng Entertainment to inform you *o*f this Public Service Exclamat*i*on:
>   Th*i*s is **NOT** a number sequence puzzle, although you w*i*ll be finding a number fr*o*m a series of numbers.
>   If you're look*i*ng down upon this sequence, I'll tell y*o*u that it's a very bas*i*c puzzle.

-uence looking puzzle that isn't actually a number sequence.

565, 721, 575, 425, 667 => 4??

(EDIT: The fourth number should have been 4TWO5 not 415!!! Super sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: The italicized letters are *i* or *o*. With "basic" I'm guessing binary, and the italicized letters become `101`,`110`,`101`.

Comment: Which makes 565, the first number of the sequence...

Comment: Or, if we do not separate them, 373.

Comment: I suspect octal numbers since no digit is over 7.

Comment: Converting from octal to decimal, the sequence is 373, 465, 381, 269, 439.  No clue what it means.  Maybe the "NOT" is relevant?

Comment: The first number is 565 (base-8), 721(base-8) is 566 (base-9). 575(base-9) is 473 (base-10). 415(base-10) is 348 (base-11). 667 (base-11) is 567 (base-12). And if we follow the 3 consecutive numbers (565, 566 and 567) 568(base 12) is 497 (base 13). Which does start with a 4, but I am not convinced.

Comment: Remember that this is NOT a number sequence puzzle :) If you're looking for a sequence relationship, you're looking in the wrong place!

Comment: I believe you would define this collection as an ordered set. The order its members matters, but it is not defined by a function.

Comment: I feel like the fact that some and not all of the i's and o's are italicized is important somehow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number is

> 416

---

As [@MikeQ](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48191/this-is-not-a-number-sequence-puzzle#comment146672_48191) and [@boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48191/this-is-not-a-number-sequence-puzzle#comment146673_48191) noted in the comments,

> The italicised letters are *ioi iio ioi*, which, when taking "basic" aka hint to binary", leads to 565, the first number in the "sequence". In addition, each line in the blockquote has three italicised letters, confirming this interpretation.

If we then do this for each number, we get

> `101 110 101`
>  `111 010 001`
>  `101 111 101`
>  `100 010 101`
>  `110 110 111`
>  formatting according to the "looking down upon this sequence" hint.

Now, we want three digits, and our grid is neatly split into three blocks, but none look particularly like a digit. However, with some nudging from the OP,

> we can re-group the bits so that all the fours bits are together, all the twos bits are together, and all the ones bits are together. For example, looking at the first row, the fours bits from left to right are `1__ 1__ 1__`, the twos bits are `_0_ _1_ _0_`, and the ones bits are `__1 __0 __1`. We can put them together to form `111 010 101`.

Doing so for each row yields

> `111 010 101`
>  `100 110 101`
>  `111 010 111`
>  `101 010 001`
>  `111 111 001`

If you can't see it yet:

> `***  *  * *`
>  `*   **  * *`
>  `***  *  ***`
>  `* *  *    *`
>  `*** ***   *`

That doesn't start with a 4 though.

> Let's flip it. (Or, more technically, take the bits in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) order).
>  `* *  *  ***`
>  `* * **  *`
>  `***  *  ***`
>  `..*  *  * *`
>  `..* *** ***`

Comment: I've been looking at this for ten minutes and still have no idea what you mean by 'We can re-group the bits so that all the fours bits are together, all the twos bits are together, and all the ones bits are together.' It would be great if you could be less vague

Comment: @Wen1now I have edited that part, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @Wen1now in other words, look at the shape the odd digits make, then look at the shape the 2+ mod 4 digits make, then look at the shape the 4+ mod 8 digits make